# Number of numbers divisible by a prime number in a row to pascal triangle

Tags: python, algorithm, primes, factorial

How can i find the total number of numbers in a given row number of a pascal triangle divisible by a prime number in which the row number and prime is given
I am using the following code in python

```
def factorial(x):
    result = 1
    for i in xrange(1,x+1):
        result *= i
    return result

def combination(n,r):
    return factorial(n)/(factorial(n-r)*factorial(r))

p = input()
cnt = 0
for i in range(0,n+1):
    if((combination(n,i)%p)==0):
        cnt += 1
print cnt
```

but the given code takes long time for big numbers.
Can you please suggest me a better algorithm.

Comment: To begin with, optimize `factorial()`.

Comment: You essentially perform computations for the function repeatedly.

Comment: You may use `memoization`‎ or dynamic programming to compute factorial faster.

Comment: But for a immensely large row number like 10^12 the computation of it is not easily done by finding combinations there must be algorithm because i have to solve it in less than a second

Comment: use math.factorial(x)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One corollary from [Luca's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem) states that number of binomial coefficients C(n,k) which are **not divisible** by prime p, is
`(a₁+1)⋅(a₂+1)⋅...⋅(am+1)`, where a<sub>i</sub> is ith digit of n **in p-ary** numeral system.

Example:

```
p = 3, n = 7dec = 213
Result = (2+1)⋅(1+1) = 6
```

7th row of Pascal triangle is `1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1`, it contains 6 coefficients not divisible by 3, and the two remaining are divisible by 3.

Comment: Thanks you very much your idea works and made the answer possible within 0.1 seconds in C and 0.27 seconds in python.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to compute the binomial coefficient `(n,r)`.

Count how often `p` is in `n!`, `r!` and `(n-r)!` and check if `n!` has more factors `p` than the other two togeter.

```
// sry... no python...
long count_p_in_fac(long n, long p)
{ 
   long count = 0;
   long i = 1;
   long temp;
   while(true)
   {
      temp = floor(n/pow(p,i));
      count += temp;
      if(temp == 0)
         break;
   }
   return count;
}

p = input()
cnt = 0
for i in range(0,n+1):
   if(count_p_in_fac(n,p) > count_p_in_fac(i,p) + count_p_in_fac(n-i,p)):
      cnt += 1
print cnt
```

This avoids big numbers and reduces the operations.

This checks `(n,r) = 0 mod p` in `O(log(n))` without computing factorials. But counting a row takes `O(n log n)`.

You can also speed this up by using the symmetry of `(n,r)`. Computing only the first half and multiply it by two. If `n` is even, you have to count the first half exept the middle `r = n/2` and check add the middle after multiply by two.

And you can precompute `count_p_in_fac(i,p)` for all `i`.

Comment: Again r! is going to be enormous given the constraints of this problem.  (I have no idea of the order of the implementation of r! but O(r) will be too slow I think).

Comment: this checks (n,r) % p == 0 in O(log(n)) without computing factorials.
But counting a row takes O(n log n).

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your combination function without needing to calculate factorial. `(n, r)` can be written recursively as

```
(n, r) = (n-1, r) + (n-1, r-1)
```

Now we should find the base cases. These are:

```
(n, 1) = n
(n, 0) = 1
(n, n) = 1
```

Here, we are assuming that `n` and `r` are non-negative integers and `n >= r` holds true. Then the function `combination` can be rewritten as

```
def combination(n, r):
    if r == 1:
        return n
    if r == 0 or r == n:
        return 1
    return combination(n-1, r) + combination(n-1, r-1)

p = input()
count = 0
for i in range(n + 1):
    if combination(n, i) % p == 0:
        count += 1

print count
```

Comment: On row 10^12 you're going to have a stack overflow in combination?

Comment: But for a large number of p it does not give result within a second. There must be a property of pascal triangle that i need

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you're going to do 10^12 in less than a second. There has to be some property of Pascall's Triangle that makes this easier.. If it's possible

> Another interesting property of Pascal's triangle is that in a row p
>   where p is a prime number, all the terms in that row except the 1s are
>   multiples of p. This can be proven easily, since if p\in \mathbb{P},
>   then p has no factors save for 1 and itself. Every entry in the
>   triangle is an integer, so therefore by definition (p-k)! and k! are
>   factors of p!\,. However, there is no possible way p itself can show
>   up in the denominator, so therefore p (or some multiple of it) must be
>   left in the numerator, making the entire entry a multiple of p.

It might have something to do with that result (from the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).. if this has an answer (i.e. if it's university homework some professor gave you).

See here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9181/pascal-triangle-and-prime-numbers

(I love this question - I'm not sure it's a programming question though).

Comment: Thanks, for you idea but for n other than p it is going to be a cumbersome task

Comment: From the mathoverflow link: "If you know what happens for powers of primes, then you can figure out what happens for any number; the binomial coefficients divisible by, say, 36 are just those divisible by both 4 and 9".

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for responding to the question of a noob like me
Here is a working python code

```
n,p = map(int,raw_input().split(' '))
if n==p:
    print n-1
elif p>n:
    print 0
else:
    result = 1
    m = n
    while n:
        temp = n%p
        result *= (temp+1)
        n /= p
    print m+1-result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = input("enter the row for pascal triangle:")
p = input("enter any prime number u want:")
cnt = 0
line = [1]
for k in range(0, n):
    line.append(line[k] * (n-k) / (k+1))
print line

lengths = map(lambda word: line[word]%p ==0, range(len(line))).count(True)
print lengths
```

Comment: Using range will give error for a big input of n so it don't work for big values of n but for small values it is cool :)

Comment: using xrange would me much more fruit full in this scenario